# Meteor.JS retrieving from Google API Problems

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, meteor

Woohoo, more Meteor questions from me!  What I'm trying to do is retrieve the user's channel "snippet" from the YouTube Data API v3.  This contains an object, with an array called `items` containing all the data I need in my application.  My current client code follows:

```
if (Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
    Meteor.http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true&access_token=" + Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result.statusCode, result.data);
        var retdata =  result.data;
        return retdata.items;
    });
}
```

Which outputs this in the client console:

```
200 
Object {kind: "youtube#channelListResponse", etag: ""eTr3dHIt5_K9qdGtRKL-5XdpiQI/4Lt-RSCeBy7D3VwX3c_uic6-LIM"", pageInfo: Object, items: Array[1]}
```

But the function returns `undefined` for some reason, which means I can't use its return values.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much work and discussion with the guys on Meteor's IRC Channel, we finally came to the working conclusion in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/4459262).

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're passing the method in which you're returning data as the second argument to `http.get` as the asynchronous callback which is called once the data is returned from the address you called. So:

```
Meteor.http.get(url, callback);
```

doesn't return anything. Instead, rather than returning an object in the callback, set it on something in a scope outside of `get` instead:

```
if (Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels";
    var params = {
      access_token: Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken,
      part: "snippet",
      mine: "true"
    };
    Meteor.http.get(url, {params: params}, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result.statusCode, result.data);
        var retdata =  result.data;
        Session.set("myItems", retdata.items);
    });
}
```

Make sure you're also publishing the `services.google.accessToken` field manually, or it won't be available on Meteor.user(). And make sure you're doing all of this in a Template or somewhere reactive where if the Meteor.user() is not yet available, Meteor will re-run the code once it is.

Comment: I tried that and it is still logging to the console, but still returning undefined for some reason.  Should I be putting it in some specific method or something, or can I just drop it straight into client.js?

Comment: Correction--it's not doing anything at all.  I'm running it in Meteor.startup in client.js.

Comment: Ah - according to [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_http), the second argument is `[options]`, not the callback, so you should pass the params as the second argument and then pass the function as the third argument. I updated the example.

Comment: That works, but only in server.js.  When I run it in client.js it doesn't write anything to either console (server terminal or client console).  Since you can't set sessions in server.js, I assume it must be in client code.  Why won't it work?  I've copied it directly from your example.

Comment: Do you have the code inside a Meteor.method or publish method? You can't invoke Meteor.user() outside those or they will throw an error. Otherwise the code works for me...

Comment: I overlooked the fact that you could use Meteor.methods on the client.  So I can just run it in a Meteor.method and then use the session after?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you wanted to run it on the client - in the client, if you copy and paste my code example into Meteor.startup it should work. I get a 403 forbidden response from youtube (since I don't send the right access token). Try replacing accesstoken with just "1" and see if that happens for you too.

Comment: I'm _still_ not getting anything.  Tried replacing the access token, tried putting it in Meteor.startup, nothing works.

Comment: Yeah, after trying literally every trick in the book, from loading it in the Google auth callback to loading it at startup to even loading it in each individual template helper, nothing will get it to work, yet you're able to get it to work immediately on a blank app.  Why won't my code work?

Comment: I have no idea. Why don't you join the Meteor IRC channel and see if someone there is able to assist you? irc.freenode.net/#meteor